# Непонятные глюки title в toolbar android

Tags: android, locale

У меня в приложении на активити есть toolbar, у которого соответственно есть свой title. Вот код тулбара в разметке:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

так как я внедрил три языка, соответственно у меня есть три файла с строковыми ресурсами для каждого языка отдельно. На текущий момент у меня есть английский, русский и украинский. Данный тулбар висит на определенной активити, и определен таким образом:

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Активити на которой находится этот виджет не основная и ошибку сразу не видно, но при переходе на активити с этим тулбаром начинаются глюки. В чем выражаются эти глюки: вот например, мы выбрали язык всего приложения английский, и заголовком этого тулбара тоже становится английский все вроде ок, но потом мы ставим русский язык, но у тулбара все-равно висит англ., и только после перезагрузки появляется русский. либо например мы выбрали укр. язык, тулбар меняется тоже на укр. (есть моменты когда он может и не тупить, но такое нечасто бывает), дальше мы меняем на анг. но на тулбаре все-равно укр. без перезагрузки ставим русский, но тулбар все-равно укр.

Я уже по-моему задавал подобный вопрос, мне сказали что тип это могут быть проблемы с ресурсами, но я проверил все с ресурсами нормально. Может быть как-то намекать тулбару на определенный заголовок, хотя я пробовал setTitle поставить и это не помогло, потому-что этой функции студия почему-то не видит.

Просто не очень красиво перезагружать приложение ради одной строки. Надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Comment: Я сталкивался с такой проблемой 2 года назад. Судя по всему ничего не поменялось, баг в андроиде остался и ничего кроме программного проставления заголовка вам не остаётся)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, посмотрите, вы имеете в виду то что я написал в ответе?

Comment: Да, именно это) Правда, я не помню в каком порядке что ставил)

Comment: может я конечно не прав, но походу порядок все-таки имеет значение) я думаю что нужно все-таки перед set говорить тулбару какой заголовок брать.

Comment: Возможно) Я так понимаю, вы в итоге смену языка сами сделали или всё же либу брали? А то мне тоже надо будет вскоре такое делать и я смотрю в сторону либы)

Comment: вы можете попроьовать переопределить метод onConfigurationChanged() - колбэк [срабатывает на изменение конфигурации](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes?hl=ru#HandlingTheChange), в том числе изменение локали стандартным способом (через настройки телефона). В этом методе вы можете провести действия, решающие проблемы изменения конфигурации

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, мне много что советовали: либу, самому сделать, даже тул на сервере))) в итоге тул я отмел, либы смотрел пробовал, но в итоге решил делать сам, мне кажется что это самый простой и стабильный способ. В этой ситуации многое может пойти не так, вот например как в этом вопросе, и нужно быстро найти и починить то что сломалось, а либа может просто не дать вам это сделать, поэтому я лучше немного больше посижу над переводом и файлами, но буду спокоен что все будет тянутся как нужно. Но это только мое мнение :)

Comment: @pavlofff, а что даст переопределение этого метода? это походу просто глюк ос, или результат может быть таким-же как и программное управление заголовком?

Comment: это колбэк системы, срабатывает на изменение конфигурации. там вы можете программно менять заголовок только при изменении языка и без перезагрузки

Comment: так я сейчас вроде тоже уже без перезагрузки это делаю) или ваш способ менее костыльный? просто вроде работает, но если ваш способ более стабильный то попробую его

Comment: это просто предложение, как вариант решения проблемы

Comment: а где его прописать нужно, просто я то вроде прочитал доки, но сложновато представить где его юзать, типа в той активити где у меня этот тулбар? или как?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как ни странно, но после публикации вопроса, пришла в голову идея, я попробовал и получилось. Мой тулбар в классе объявлен так:

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

я пробовал ставить title после `setSupportActionBar`, я нужно перед. В итоге получается такой код:

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
toolbar.setTitle(R.string.title_activity_message_center);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Не уверен что мой вопрос-ответ кому-то поможет, но может всякое быть )